# Is this a JOIN, Lookup or how to select only records matching a col from two tables

Tags: postgresql, join, lookup

I have two postgres tables where one column listing a city name matches. I'm trying to create a view of some records which I'm displaying on a map via WMS on my GeoServer.

I need to select only records from table1 of 100k records that has a city name that matches those cities listed in table2 of 20 records.

To list everything I've tried would be a waste of your time. I've tried every join tutorial and example but, am perplexed why I can't get any success. I would really appreciate some direction.

Here's a latest query but, if this is the wrong approach just ignore since I have about 50 similar attempts.

```
SELECT t1.id,  
       t1.dba,  
       t1.prem_city,  
       t1.geom  
       t2.city_label  
FROM schema1.table1 AS t1  
     LEFT JOIN schema2.table2 AS t2  
        ON t2.city_label = t1.prem_city;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems correct, just a minor change - `LEFT JOIN` keeps all the records from the left table and only the matching record from the right one. If you want only those that appear in both - an `INNER JOIN` is required .

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.dba,
       t1.prem_city,
       t1.geom,
       t2.city_label
FROM schema1.table1 t1
JOIN schema2.table2 t2
 ON t2.city_label = t1.prem_city;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried your direct example and INNER JOIN and getting empty results. To back up a bit, when talking about a join it seems this implies I'm creating a third table of sorts (if only in a view) of combined records. When actually all I want is any record in table1 that has a match city name from table2. Other results I've seen were all records returned from t1 with the city_label from t2 completely empty (my assumption being if there was a match, it would list those cities in t2 in the combined view. I'm certainly missing something.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to Select only records where that one column from both tables matches. I have a bunch of other uses for this approach so I didn't want to hard-code the query in (as the list of cities will be fluid as well). That's why I was asking if this is instead a lookup function? If you could take it one more step and suggest which join condition I should use that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What I did: an INNER JOIN (parsed by pgAdmin4 as 'JOIN' below, of the   smaller table of city names and FIPS codes (aliased as t1) against bigger   table t2 where a match for 'city' was found from both.      

In this example I added an additional WHERE filter to parse out a   selection of records from cities that had the code 44000 (Los Angeles) or   22412 (El Segundo).    

    'FROM MySchema1Name.MyTable1Name t1'  
    'JOIN myTable2Name t2 ON t1.myTable1Column = t2.myTable2Column'  
    'WHERE t2.myTable2Column2 = '44000' OR t2.myTable2Column2 = '22412';'  
  
Thanks sagi!